# JASidePanels Show Menu Button on Right?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using JASidePanels in iOS and trying to get the menu button to show on the right instead of the left (center panel is a UINavigationController so the left menu button gets replaced with the back button text) but I cannot seem to get the right button to show regardless of what I try.

I tried setting only a right panel (no left panel).  Is there a way within JASidePanels to move the menu button from the left side of the navigation bar to the right side?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a new bar button to the navigation bar within your viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Right"
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(toggleRightPanel)];
```

and method to be called by right bar button:

```
- (void)toggleRightPanel {
    [[self.parentViewController valueForKey:@"sidePanelController"] performSelector:@selector(toggleRightPanel:)];

}
```